# JScrollBar doesn't show the thumb

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

When I set visibleAmount of JScrollBar equal with maximum Value, the thumb of JScrollbar is disappear. I don't know why?
and i want to make the scrollbar like that: [<][ --- ][>] (the size of thumb is full of JScrollbar).

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If the JScrollBar is part of a JScrollPane you can choose the visibility policy:

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPanel(aPanel);
pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

For example the code above make the horizontal scrollbar always visible.

EDIT:

if you are creating your custom JScrollBar to scroll a component, you should consider to use a JScrollPane and [add it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBar%28javax.swing.JScrollBar%29) to your scrollpane:

```
JScrollBar bar = new YourCustomScrollBar();
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(bar); 
pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: The Jscrollbar is not a part of JScrollPane. I just create a new JScrollbar()

Comment: what are you using the JScrollBar for? could you post the code?

Comment: For my requirement, i want to create new JScrollBar(), I've just edited the post

Comment: Hi, I can not use JScrollPane, so i have to cheat code, when the Visible Amount = Maximum value, i will set Maximum = 10000, and VisibleAmount = 9999, it make the thumb appear and it seems that the size of thumn is full of JScrollbar